# What is the best practice for calling a REST API when a component is shown for the first time?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rest, redux, react-redux

Let's say I am implementing a simple ToDo list in React Native, where the list is stored remotely via a REST API.

Let's say I have a `GET /list` endpoint to fetch the list of ToDo items.

Now let's say I have a component, defined as a function, to render the list:

```
function TodoList(): JSX.Element {
    // Use selector gets a value out of the state
    const state: State = useSelector((state: any) => state.list);

    // Use dispatch gives us a handle to dispatch actions
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (<View>
        // .. render the list htere
    </View>)
}
```

Let's say I also have a thunk defined which fetches the list:

```
export const fetchList = (dispatch: any, getState: any) => {
    dispatch(setListFetchState(FetchState.Fetching))
            fetch(`http://{HOST}/item`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((result) => {
                dispatch(setListData(result))
            })
        }
}
```

So the behavior I want is: the first time the TodoList component is rendered, it should dispatch `fetchList` in order to load the initial data from the API.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried inserting:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchList)
    })
```

inside my component function, but this seems to result in `fetchList` being dispatched in an infinite loop.

What is the best practice for ensuring that this thunk is only executed once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did not add any dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchList)
    })
```

this means every time your component rerenders, this `useEffect` will run. and since you are dispatching an action to redux store, changing the state, will cause a rerender, so `useEffect` will re run again

since you want the first time  it runs, you need to add an empty array as a dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchList)
    },[])
```

Comment: Thank you - just so I understand, what exactly is the empty arrange doing?

Comment: you basically tell react when you want to run the code inside the useEffect. there are 3 cases. 1- empty array. code inside will run only when component mounted. 2- no dependency arrray. useEffect code will run every time your component rerenders. 3- you can add dependencies so that you want to run useEffect code only those dependencies change. this is the most annoying part. you have to be careful about what dependencies to put. you could easily create infinte loop